# How to reduce the margins when using book?

Tags: margins

I do not want to specify the margins to use such as the following because I get uniform margins on odd and even pages. Instead I would like to set that I want to reduce the default margins by 30%.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
```

Is it possible to do this such as:

```
\set\margins{small} % large, medium, ...
```

Comment: You can set the margins with `[lmargin=.···, rmargin= ···]` to have different values for the inner and the outer margin.

Comment: @Bernard, but still I have to specify 4 values... `top`, `bottom`, `lmargin` and `rmargin`. Since I don't know the original values for those, it is complicated. How should I proceed if I want 70% of these values?

Comment: Well you just compute the values you want. What's the problem? What do you mean with ‘the original values’?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have well understood may be this will help

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
  \usepackage[width=0.7\textwidth,height=0.7\textheight]{geometry}
  \usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
  \Blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Uh, that will increase the margins.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Yeah I wanted to reduce it. but I  guess you could use `1.3\textwidth`

Answer (score 1):

This precomputes the default margins and stores them in (unused) length registers.  One could probably put the `\dimexpr` expressions directly into the geometry arguments, but I wanted to make sure nothing changed on the fly.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\dimen0=\dimexpr \oddsidemargin+1in\relax% compute default left margin
\dimen1=\dimexpr \paperwidth-\textwidth-\dimen0\relax% right maregin
\dimen2=\dimexpr \topmargin+\headheight+\headsep+1in\relax% top
\dimen3=\dimexpr \paperheight-\textheight-\dimen2\relax% bottom

\usepackage[a4paper, left=0.7\dimen0, right=0.7\dimen1, top=0.7\dimen2, bottom=0.7\dimen3,
  marginpar=0.7\marginparwidth, showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-7]
\end{document}
```

Comment: It would certainly be a good answer, but it is so cumbersome that I feel bad to accept this answer :(